# IPA setup creation FAILED

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to build AwayPhysics for iOS.
But when i compiling release/ad-hoc or even (slow-debug) under FD:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.merge(GlobalOptimizer.java:9985)
at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.readCode(GlobalOptimizer.java:1265
)
at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.readBody(GlobalOptimizer.java:685)

at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.readBodies(GlobalOptimizer.java:40
4)
at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.generateBitcode(LLVMEmitter.java:331)
at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.convertAbcToLlvmBitcodeImpl(AOTCompiler
.java:611)
at com.adobe.air.ipa.BitcodeGenerator.main(BitcodeGenerator.java:104)
Compilation failed while executing : ADT
```

I've tested with:
Adobe Air 3.4 (Flex SDK)
Adobe Air 3.5 (Flex SDK)
Adobe Air 3.6 (Flex SDK)
Adobe Air 3.7 (Flex SDK)
Adobe Air 3.8 Beta (Flex SDK)

Adobe Air 3.7 (ASCSDK)
Adobe Air 3.8 (ASCSDK)

I've also tried "-optimize=false" nothing helps.

Only fast-interpreter mode works which is really slow!

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download AwayPhysics (Bullet physics ontop of flascc)
   https://github.com/away3d/awayphysics-core-fp11/tree/dev
   or Oimophysics
2. Build any sample or just include AWPDynamicWorld

Update:

After increasing heap memory size to -Xms1024m -Xmx1524m:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.HashSet.<init>(Unknown Source)
at adobe.abc.Algorithms$SetMap.get(Algorithms.java:226)
at adobe.abc.Algorithms.addUses(Algorithms.java:165)
at adobe.abc.Algorithms.findUses(Algorithms.java:187)
at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp(GlobalOptimizer.java:4731)
at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:3615)
at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:2309)
at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.optimizeABCs(LLVMEmitter.java:532)
at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.generateBitcode(LLVMEmitter.java:341)
at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.convertAbcToLlvmBitcodeImpl(AOTCompiler
.java:611)
at com.adobe.air.ipa.BitcodeGenerator.main(Bitcod

eGenerator.java:104)
    Compilation failed while executing : ADT
```

Comment: I suspect you have many SWF files as assets in this project.  Do they have ActionScript in them (i.e. stop(), gotoAndPlay, etc) on the timeline?  If not, perhaps you can package them in a way that would avoid the iOS cross-compilation step (which is what takes all the time/memory).  Also, ADT kicks off many Java child processes.  Watch those processes with `ps -aef | grep -i java` and see whether the Java heap size parameters are correct on the sub-processes.  If not, try setting the global environment variable `JAVA_OPTS='-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m'` instead of using the jvm.config file.

Comment: You can also set java memory params (`-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`) for the given SDK in the Eclipse: `Window->Preference->Java->Installed JREs->Your JRE->Default VM Arguments`

Comment: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013384/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: Tried everything. Still does not works.

Comment: As i said its pretty easy to reproduce the bug. There is no additional libraries swc or swf.

Comment: btw i have 16gb ram but when i set "Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" adt says that it is too much.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to increase the "maximum heap size" (maximum amount of memory reserved) for the Java Virtual Machine.

You can configure this setting in **jvm.config**, which is located in **sdk_install_dir/bin**.

> To change the maximum heap size, change the value of the Xmx property. The following example sets the initial heap size to 256M and the maximum heap size to 512M:
>
> `java.args=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false`

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd9.html

Comment: I've tried this. Same error. I'm not sure that this bug related to Java or memory. I've 32 gb ram. Java Version: 1.6 32, 64bit, 1.7. Tried everything and different sdks.

Comment: The error message you posted strongly points to insufficient heap size though. What value did you set -Xms to?